# Animation of a hose or pipe created with a Bézier curve

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I was trying to create an animation of the movement of a hose constructed with a curve (Bezier).

If I understand correctly, there is no bezier animation as such? I can set the animation for the movement of an object on a curve, but there is no animation for the curve itself. If I understand it correctly, is it because the change of the shape and length of the hose is set by the change of the curve and the change of the curve is not done in *Object Mode* but in *Edit Mode*?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right, there is no "direct" animation possibility. But there are multiple "indirect" possibilities to do it.

- One is, to use Hooks (which are "bound" empties) to your vertices of your curve which you then can animate.
- another one is to use geometry nodes with which you can access each vertex of the curve and move it by the "set position" node. By using other nodes like math nodes and scene time you can create any curve animation you want
- exactly the same (and even more) is possible with the free add-on "animation nodes" which gives you even more freedom because e.g. you can even create your own nodes via python so you can use the whole Blender API and not just the nodes the developers provide you
- and of course you could also animate the curve directly via python which give you the most grade of freedom - but it is of course also not that easy if you aren't familiar with python and Blender's API
- you can even give your curve a soft body modifier - so it will be animated as well. And as you know you can influence this animation by e.g. forces, collision objects etc...